# Testing a pipeline without constantly executing a trigger

Tags: github, gitlab, continuous-integration, github-actions, pipeline

Perhaps others have noticed that it can be very tedious when building a GitHub or GitLab pipeline. For every new change that you want to you want to test, you have to initialize a PR or push etc. This can take a long time. In the long run this can be be quite annoying in the long run.

**Question** Are there any workarounds/ tools etc. that you can use to test a pipeline without having to without having to create a PR or perform a merge or other trigger every time. has to be done.

Comment: I know the problem and would also like to know what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

The only way of not having to push your changes to github would mean having the pipeline execution locally. There seems to be a tool for it:
https://github.com/nektos/act (haven't used it myself)

**About having to create a PR or merge to trigger**

That's something you define yourself in the workflow file. While working on a workflow via your feature branch you could configure it to trigger to push event for your branch.

So feedback process would mean:

1. Perform local changes
2. Push to feature branch
3. Look at the result

When happy with the result, update the triggers to comply with your requirements (e.g trigger only on pull request etc).

That is usually fast enough in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the link (*/act). that looks very interesting! I will check it out. all the best!